# What to do when catching e(rror) in Java

Tags: java

In Java, I see a lot of codes like below.
What I am wondering is, is it enough just to show error message?

I am new to Java. What I want to learn is how to handle error efficiently, and know best practices for error-handling. In general, what should I do in catch block?

## Example 1 : printStackTrace()

```
} catch (SomeException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

## Example 2 : getMessage

```
} catch (SomeException e) {
    e.getMessage();
}
```

## Example 3 : show custom error message

```
} catch (IOException E) {
    System.out.println("Error occured. Please try again.");
}
```

Comment: Using a Logger is preferred. Like Amila answered...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, the answer is *depends*. Do what your business logic asking for.

- If you want to log it, log it.
- If you want to see the error in console, print it to there.
- If you want to throw back to the method caller, go do it.

There are no of possibilities and needs depending on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you starting with Exception section in [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

What you should do in the catch block depends on your application.

Generally, if you're just logging the error, you should include the stacktrace to make debugging easier.

```
logger.error("Error occurred.", e);
```

Answer (score 0):

e.printStackTrace prints the message to the console, you can use this when the user sees the console...

e.getMessage() return a String, so you can handle as you wish, like:

```
try {

} catch (IOException E) {
    System.out.println("Error occured. Please try again."+ e.getMessage());
}
```

or use the getMessage() when you have no console, but, for instance, a GUI, you can set:

```
textField.setText(e.getMessage());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should log the error using a Logger so you can decide where to write the excetion (es. a file) and also do something else, depending what your code is doing.
For example if you are writing into a database you should rollback the data to the previous state.

I also suggest you not to suppresses the exception, but let the "user" know something went wrong. You can catch the exception and wrap it into another one with a message more user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

you can also redirect to another page like error page while getting any exception in the try catch block . 
you can also describe the error on the html page .
so user redirect to the error page if there are exception in catch block.

Answer (score -1):

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

the above could be good practice since it will trace the stack and show what and where the problem is

Comment: what if there is no console?

Comment: yes you can use either of them depending on the situation.